# How to create Kafka topic from a JSON file and then extract subset of the topic and output to another JSON file

Tags: json, apache-kafka

I am new with Kafka tool.
Here are the steps I would like to perform in Kafka:

1. Connect Kafka and input data from a JSON file (I am familiar with this part)
2. Publish to a Kafka topic
3. Extract subset of data from the topic and publish (create) to a new topic
4. Extract data from that new topic and output to a JSON file

Note: my coding preference is Python.

Comment: Because you've shown no research or attempt at a solution and seem to be asking someone to write code for you

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use Python, you can use [Faust](https://github.com/robinhood/faust) to map data between topics

By default, it uses JSON serialization, and if you want to write to a new file, you want to consume [through](https://faust.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/streams.html#through-forward-through-another-topic) a stream

Comment: Rather, I am looking for a solution in Kafka.

Comment: Your question definitely said Python... Kafka itself offers nothing like you're asking for